# Armazenando SOCKET em um vetor

Tags: c, c++, socket

Estou trabalhando em um projeto desenvolvido em c/c++ aonde um servidor manipula várias conexões, não tenho muita experiência nessa linguagem, gostaria de saber como devo proceder para adicionar um SOCKET em um vetor, para poder acessa-lo em seguida.

Comment: c/c++ nao 'e uma linguagem. Ou 'e C ou 'e C++. Embora parecidas, cada linguagem tem as suas particularidades (que podem nao funcionar correctamente na outra linguagem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode estar criando uma estrutura de dados

```
/* Struct Client */  
struct HYPNOS_STRUCT
{
    SOCKET socket;
};
```

Logo em seguida defina um vetor de estruturas com a estrutura criada acima.

```
const int MAX_CLIENTS = 50;
std::vector<HYPNOS_STRUCT> hypnos_client(MAX_CLIENTS);
```

Sendo assim, logo que aceitar um novo socket você pode estar acessando uma posição 
de seu vetor para adiciona-lo!

```
SOCKET incoming = INVALID_SOCKET;
incoming = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_info, &addrsize);

hypnos_client[i].socket = incoming;
```

Comment: Existe alguma vantagem em utilizar a `struct` em relação à um `SOCKET` ou ponteiro para `SOCKET`(`std::vector<SOCKET*> sockets;`) direto?

Comment: eu uso a estrutura para manipular diversos dados que um cliente pode ter, por exemplo Hostname, iD, Username ai já fica tudo organizado para aquele cliente naquela posição do vetor

Comment: @Rhayden Muito Obrigado!

Comment: /o precisando,estamos ai!  :)